# MegaCli Using write through instead of write back

Tags: megacli

My DB server is a dell r710 with megacli. Recently was getting poor performance from the database and stumbled across that the current cache policy is WT but the default cache policy is WB.

```
# ./MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aAll | grep 'Cache Policy:'
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteThrough, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
```

Looking some though some of the other articles on here, is only occurs when the battery is faulty. Looking at the BBU it looks like its good.

```
# ./MegaCli64 -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -aALL | grep isSOHGood
isSOHGood: Yes
```

Am I missing something? How can I change this to be WriteBack so I can get the performance back.

Thanks!

Comment: Some controllers change the policy while battery learning cycle and switch back after that. Maybe your controller missed that switch back.

Comment: I have seen that as well but looking at the logs and at the BBU Fireware status the learn cycle is not active. "Learn Cycle Active: No"

Answer (score 3):

You can switch back the policy back to WB with

```
megacli -LDSetProp WB -LAll -aAll
```

After that you can check the current state with

```
megacli -LDInfo -LAll -aAll
```

Comment: Already tried enabling writeback and trying to force it with the -Immediate. No change in the current cache policy.

Comment: do you have dell? might be that the command create jobs in the idrac job queue, which you can run then

Answer (score 3):

Use the force luke

> megacli -LDSetProp -ForcedWB -Immediate -Lall -aAll

I wouldn't set Forced WriteBack under heavy load, but your main problem right now seems to be a faulty BBU so I would double check it. Normally the BBU should be replaced every 1-5 years and regulary checked.

If

> megacli -AdpBbuCmd -GetBbuStatus -aALL

really doesn't say anything about learning required or a faulty battery than maybe a firmware upgrade is required.
To check the version:

> megacli -AdpAllInfo -aAll

To update the firmware:

> MegaCli -adpfwflash -f firmware.rom -a0

Be carefull and good luck with your raid.